# Characterize the points inside a medial triangle

Tags: geometry

A triangle $\triangle ABC$ is formed by joining the mid-points of the sides of a triangle $\triangle ABC$. If 
$O$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$, then for $\triangle PQR$ the point $O$ is ?
[image]

The options are 
(i) incentre, (ii) circumcentre, (iii) orthocentre, (iv) centroid

What will be the correct answer and how can I say this? Thank you